# View complete HTTP request including Headers

Tags: http, servlets, soap

I am working on SOAP using apache axis.

To know the inner workings of SOAP I want to view complete HTTP Requests and Responses (including Headers) and possibly dump them into a file.

I know there is getHeader method but it is for extraction specific headers but I want the complete request text.

Also is there any way to view generated HTTP requests and responses on the web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Fiddler? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
And I use FireBug for Firefox to see request and responses

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.fiddler2.com

It will show you everything you could ever want to see as far as http requests/responses from a browser.

Comment: Okay..but what about the server side